# Creating xml through jsp

Tags: html, jsp, netbeans-platform

I want to create an xml file using jsp. The xml file should contain multiple details as in employee details. The value for the xml tag is from html page. Every time the button is clicked, a new set of tags should be created under the employee tag, for each employee.

Comment: Can u pls tel , why do u want to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

create a javascript function for the button in your jsp page. For creating the dynamic xml document, in the javascript function include the jsp tag for creating the file with the extension of xml, like this,

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.xml", "UTF-8");
writer.println("<tag1>"+value1+"</tag1>");
writer.println("<tag2>"+value2+"</tag2>");
writer.close();
```

where values are obtained from the html pagge.